# Why can't I use a method on this parameter?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use the `Where` method on the collection in this overloaded method:

```
Private Function getIndexOfObjectById(Of T)(ByVal collection As SortableBindingList(Of T), ByVal id As Integer)
    Dim cy = collection.Where(Function(c) c.id = id).FirstOrDefault()
    Return collection.IndexOf(cy)
End Function
```

But I get an error, even though I know the method exists:

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of T, Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of T)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of T, Integer, Boolean)'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of T, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of T)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': 'id' is not a member of 'T'. \\...   5693    18
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler has no way to guarantee that your generic type `T` will have a property named "id". Therefore, the `c.id` expression in your `Where()` call is not legal, because that property may not exist.

To fix this, you need to *constrain* your generic method to some interface that promises an `id` integer property will be available, have the method ask for a function that will project your type `T` to an `id`, or use some other trick that will allow the compiler to know more about your type or the projection of the type to an id integer.

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't use strong typing? I tried, and when I removed the typed parameters, I got a runtime exception claiming my collection didn't have the 'Where' method.

Comment: If you don't want strong typing, you're using the wrong platform. I mean, you could make this work with dynamic, but that's really for edge cases. It will cause a performance hit for the run-time type lookup, and will leave you open to bugs that manifest at runtime if the method is called with the wrong kind of argument.